# How to harden SSH on CentOS 6.5

Tags: ssh, centos

I have a new (first time) CentOS 6.5 server being used for a web server. Our security team has identified the following weakness:

The SSH server is configured to allow either MD5 or 96-bit MAC algorithms, both of which are considered weak.   Note that this plugin only checks for the options of the SSH server and does not check for vulnerable software versions.

Plugin Output The following client-to-server Method Authentication Code (MAC) algorithms  are supported :    hmac-md5   hmac-md5-96   hmac-sha1-96

How do I disable MD5 and/or 96-bit MAC algorithms on a CentOS 6.5 server? I tried running: authconfig --disablemd5 --updateall but still had the same issue.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/563386/openssh-on-centos-6-5

Comment: Okay - the serverfault one is on hold, so let's keep this one. For future reference, please do not cross post.

Comment: Well, you can use certificate authorization. it will be much more secure than password.

Comment: Relevant: [Secure Secure Shell](https://stribika.github.io/2015/01/04/secure-secure-shell.html)

Comment: Doesn't removing the entries stop presentation of the ciphers during the negotiation period?

Answer (score 11):

I am not completely sure, but you may want to look at the protocol setting in `sshd_config`.

From http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH

```
# Protocol 2,1
Protocol 2
```

Change Protocol 1 to Protocol 2 and restart. This should already be set to `Protocol 2` in Centos 6.5, but you may want to double check.

I found this run down of the different protocol options

http://www.snailbook.com/faq/ssh-1-vs-2.auto.html

Not sure if that is going to be enough to solve your particular issue though.

Do you know what they are using to check the configuration?

UPDATED:

This is from running `man sshd_config` on

```
Ciphers
         Specifies the ciphers allowed for protocol version 2 in order of preference.  Multiple ciphers must be comma-separated.  The supported ciphers are
         “3des-cbc”, “aes128-cbc”, “aes192-cbc”, “aes256-cbc”, “aes128-ctr”, “aes192-ctr”, “aes256-ctr”, “arcfour128”, “arcfour256”, “arcfour”,
         “blowfish-cbc”, and “cast128-cbc”.  The default is:

            aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,
            aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,
            aes256-cbc,arcfour
```

Also the `Macs` option:

```
MACs    Specifies the MAC (message authentication code) algorithms in order of preference.  The MAC algorithm is used in protocol version 2 for data
         integrity protection.  Multiple algorithms must be comma-separated.  The default is:

               hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,
               hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96,
               hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
```

So I would take a look through those and set the options in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file with the ciphers and macs that you want.

Comment: I believe the tool is called Nessus or Tenable Security Scanner.

Comment: That is actually a pretty good scanner.

Comment: Changing to explicit `Protocol 2` didn't work for me, I had to specify the Ciphers and MACs list (also as a result of a Nessus external scan).

Answer (score 7):

Add the following 2 lines to your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
Ciphers aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
MACs hmac-sha1
```

Restart services. Boom. FIPS compliant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OpenSSH isn't certified as FIPS compliant. You might be using FIPS algorithms, but that doesn't mean you are FIPS compliant.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: people talking about 'FIPS compliant/compliance' usually mean FIPS**140** **validated**, but read literally OpenSSH does comply with FIPS197 FIPS46-3 (even though withdrawn) FIPS198-1 FIPS180. Somewhat more seriously, most OpenSSH builds (still) use OpenSSL for crypto primitives and OpenSSL can _optionally_ be built to use an internal FIPS140 module that is validated on _some_ platforms; the exact list has changed repeatedly so check the links at https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips.html

Comment: Prefix the `Ciphers` in the list with `+` and `-` instead of hardcoding a list that will make _future_ configurations less secure than they could be by default.

Answer (score 7):

It's 2017 and it's time to update the recommendations.
Now both all *-CBC and RC4 ciphers are considered weak.
So we are left with:

```
MACs hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
Ciphers aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
```

Or for anything newer that supports OpenSSH 6.7 and above:

```
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr

MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com
```

Source: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Guidelines/OpenSSH#Configuration

Comment: Thank you - I had to re-add     *hmac-sha1*      to the MACs line, but otherwise this fixed my needs

Answer (score 0):

I found [this post](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/187318/faq-how-do-i-disable-cipher-block-chaining-cbc-mod.html) that may be helpful. It states that by adding the following lines:

```
 Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128
 MACs hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
```

to the `sshd` config (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) you can remove these weak MACs.